# PHP Array duplicates entries and doesn't record data values

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if anyone had the time to look at my code and give me a hand please.  Basically I have a form I downloaded which allows me to click on "add row" and it adds as many input boxes as I need which works just fine.

The problem is that when I add them to the DB, it duplicates entries and in addition I don't get the array values, only the single values.

**For example: If I add 2 entries, I get 4 entries in the DB and they all look like this:**

client_ID | item_date | item_code | item_name | qty   | cost  | added_user

5      | 2020-07-06| Array     | Array     | Array | Array | Me

PHP Code

```
function escape($html) {
    return htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8");
}

if (isset($_POST['add_items'])) {
$entries = array( $item_code, $item_name, $qty, $cost);

$client_id = $_POST['client_id'];
$item_date = date("Y-m-d");
$added_user = $_SESSION['usr'];

foreach ($entries as $row) {

    $data = array(
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'item_date' => $item_date,
        'item_code' => $item_code,
        'item_name' => $item_name,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'cost' => $cost,
        'added_user' => $added_user
        
    );

    $query = "INSERT INTO `invoiceitems` SET ";
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        $fields[] = "`$field` = '$value'";
    }
    $fields = implode(', ', $fields);
    $query .= $fields;

    mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
  
}
```

HTML FORM

```
  <tr class="item-row">
      <td><input name="item_code[]"  autocomplete="off" /></td>
      <td><input name="item_name[]" autocomplete="off" /></td>
      <td><input name="cost[]" autocomplete="off" /></td>
      <td><input name="qty[]" autocomplete="off" /></td>
      <td><span class="price"></span></td>
  </tr>
```

I have looked over many examples and I'm stuck. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance!

ENTIRE CODE:

```
<?php
include('../includes/main.php');
include_once('../includes/config.php');


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="../js/global.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="../js/modal.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        
        
        

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print.css' media="print" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/example.js'></script>
    


    
    </head>
    <body>
    
<?php include_once('../includes/header.php'); ?>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="minwidth">
                <div id="holder">
<?php $current = 3; include_once('../includes/navigation.php'); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['usr']))
{
echo "<p align='center'><font color='#F78181'>You need to be logged in to view this page.</font></p>";
}
else{
    
    
$client_id = $_POST['client_id'];

$query = "select * from clients where id = '$client_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    


//$client_id = $_POST['client_id'];

$item_code = $_POST['item_code'];
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$cost = $_POST['cost']; 



/// /// ADD INVOICE ITEMS 

function escape($html) {
    return htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "UTF-8");
}

if (isset($_POST['add_items'])) {


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$entries = array( $item_code, $item_name, $qty, $cost);

$client_id = $_POST['client_id'];
$item_date = date("Y-m-d");
$added_user = $_SESSION['usr'];

foreach ($entries as $row) {

    $data = array(
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'item_date' => $item_date,
        'item_code' => $item_code,
        'item_name' => $item_name,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'cost' => $cost,
        'added_user' => $added_user
        
    );

    $query = "INSERT INTO `invoiceitems` SET ";
    $fields = array();
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        $fields[] = "`$field` = '$value'";
    }
    $fields = implode(', ', $fields);
    $query .= $fields;

    mysqli_query($con, $query);
}
  
}





/// end ADD INVOICE ITEMS
    
?>              
                    <div id="desc">
                        <div class="body">
    <div id="html" class="help">
        

    <div id="page-wrap">

        <textarea id="header">INVOICE</textarea>
        
        <div id="identity">
        
<textarea id="address">
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
            { 
            
            echo "$row[first_name] $row[last_name]";
            echo "\n$row[address] $row[address2]";
            echo "\n$row[riding] $row[postal_code]";
            echo "\n$row[city] $row[province]";
            echo "\n$row[whatsapp]";
            echo "\n$row[phone1]";
            echo "\n$row[phone2]";
            echo "\n$row[phone3]";          
            }
}
?>

</textarea>

            <div id="logo">

              <div id="logoctr">
                <a href="javascript:;" id="change-logo" title="Change logo">Change Logo</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" id="save-logo" title="Save changes">Save</a>
                |
                <a href="javascript:;" id="delete-logo" title="Delete logo">Delete Logo</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel-logo" title="Cancel changes">Cancel</a>
              </div>

              <div id="logohelp">
                <input id="imageloc" type="text" size="50" value="" /><br />
                (max width: 540px, max height: 100px)
              </div>
              <img id="image" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        
        <div id="customer">
<textarea id="customer-title">J.D. Auto Center</textarea>
<form name="add_items" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8"  method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" />
<?php 
echo "<input type='hidden' name='client_id' value='$_POST[client_id]' />"; ?>
            <table id="meta">
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
                    <td><textarea>000123</textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="meta-head">Date</td>
                    <td><textarea id="date"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="meta-head">Amount Due</td>
                    <td><div class="due"></div></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
        
        <table id="items">
          <tr>
              <th>Item</th>
              <th>Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
              <th>Pre&ccedil;o de Unidade</th>
              <th>Quantidade</th>
              <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
          
          <tr class="item-row">
              <td><input name="item_code[]"  autocomplete="off" /></td>
              <td><input name="item_name[]" autocomplete="off" /></td>
              <td><input name="cost[]" autocomplete="off" /></td>
              <td><input name="qty[]" autocomplete="off" /></td>
              <td><span class="price"></span></td>
          </tr>

              
          
          <tr id="hiderow">
            <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
          </tr>
          
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="total"></div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>

              <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
              <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
              <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due"></div></td>
          </tr>
        
        </table>
        
<input type="submit" class="button" name="add_items" value="SALVAR" /></p>
</form>
        
        <div id="terms">
          <h5>Terms</h5>
          <textarea>Agradecemos a preferencia.</textarea>
          
          <?php
          var_dump($_POST);
          var_dump($entries);
          
          ?>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>


    
    
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div id="body_footer">
                            <div id="bottom_left"><div id="bottom_right"></div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php include_once('../includes/footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($entries);` so you understand the structure of your data. Also, you aren't using the `$row` in your `foreach` loop at all. To fix, 1. understand your data, 2. understand what your code does, don't simply mimic examples, 3. turn your error reporting on to maximum so you get insight into your errors (which are many, but which you don't currently see).

Answer (score 1):

Looping through `$entries = array( $item_code, $item_name, $qty, $cost);` is not correct. You will have to loop through post data array of each item in invoice.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `invoiceitems` (`client_id`, `item_date`, `item_code`, `item_name`, `qty`, `cost`, `added_user`) VALUES ";
$insert_rows = array();
//loop through item_code post data, inside this loop we will get other row data
foreach ($_POST['item_code'] as $k => $item_code_data) {

    $insert_fields = array($client_id, $item_date, $item_code_data, $_POST['item_name'][$k], $_POST['qty'][$k], $_POST['cost'][$k], $added_user);

    $insert_rows[] = implode("', '", $insert_fields);
}

if(count($insert_rows) > 0){
    $insert_rows_data = " ('" . implode("'), ('", $insert_rows) . "') ";
    mysqli_query($con, $query . $insert_rows_data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this and providing the code that works. Although data is being inserted correctly, it only inserts one row, ignoring all others. Any ideas?

Comment: Loop works based on value in `item_code`, so if it's left empty the whole process will not work proper. The assumption I had was that `item_code` will be mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see more of the code on the   html side but my first thought is that the name is of each entry is being duplicated with no iterration. For example. If it adds a new tag with name="name" and the next one you add it also gives it name="name" where it should be adding a iteration like name= "name1" . After that the post page needs to be able to get all post data with variable names of an unknown quantity. . I have had good luck with while(isset($_POST) and then a for loop to iterate over the name variable. But i would need to see a more complete code set

Comment: Hi Jaffrey. I posted the entire code in my question. Thank you